# Остановить работу функции при нажатии на блок

Tags: jquery, javascript, функции

Можно ли сделать чтобы при нажатии на блок какая-то функция перестала выполняться, отключилась?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, добавьте в скрипт флаг (глобальную переменную например), который будет стоять в начале функции, например:

```
var flag = false;

function test() {
    if(flag) return;

    console.log(new.Date().toString());
}

setInterval(test, 1000);

$('#block').on('click', function() {
    flag = true;
});
```

Comment: А не проще ли сделать так:

    $('#pin').on('click', function() {
        flag = !flag;
        alert(flag);
    })

Comment: @navi1893 так, стоп) Включаем логику. 

Вслух давайте: если флаг = false, то флаг = true, иначе флаг = false;


    if(flag == true) {
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        flag = true;
    }

Либо же просто применить логическое отрицание:

    flag = !flag;

Comment: Загляните в консоль, если у вас вылезла какая-то ошибка, там она отобразится. В Chrome - F12, в Firefox - Ctrl+Shift+I.

Comment: flag is not defined, пишет. Написал boolean flag = true; не работает =/

Comment: Выложите код на jsFiddle, без этого разобраться будет сложно.